# Pass form as json to controller and parse

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I have dynamically generated forms so I need to handle an unknown amount of inputs being passed to the controller. There can be no predefined model (I assume) to handle this so I figure sending a json string might be best.

The problem is parsing the json in the controller to JObject.

Here is what I'm using before submitting with an ajax request.

```
var json = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
```

now the string passed to the controller looks as follows

```
"\"__RequestVerificationToken=FGhUgZXRTWcDqC-ffeMb7S2paAgFSUN4XyJl72qu85TD1GPpi69aGiyHzXBfHpb6XgBrGXAhtJz6NWka0XGK_JRSqpm-Q41tiYvJe1NO3J-_4leHroUvDp3VsWYMLFMm0&Form.ID=d7025ad7-745b-4898-ad40-350ef1d511ec&a5fbdde8-4c34-48e2-9a77-083c31eb1ae1=This+is+a+test\""
```

In the controller

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json); //error

foreach (var o in jo)
{
    string key = o.Key;
    JToken val = o.Value;
}
```

The error i'm getting

```
"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path ''
```

Comment: Why do you have to use JSON? It seems an unnecessary complication. `x-www-form-urlencoded` is pretty standard - especially for non-AJAX requests

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you provide an example? This is being submitted via ajax. The controller can't use a predefined model because the inputs are unknown to the controller. The data being sent is using the ID of the input as the key.

Comment: You're calling JSON.stringify on a string (the result of [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)). Thus, when you parse the JSON, it returns a string, as the error says. See [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184624/215552) for how to make an object from form data.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if I take away JSON.stringify I then get `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: _. Path ''`

Comment: `The controller can't use a predefined model because the inputs are unknown to the controller.` Why not just loop through the `Request.Params` then?

Comment: @Tsukasa Did you read the question and answers in that link? Because then you would see how to send an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of better options:

- Use a `FormCollection` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx as the sole parameter in your controller method, and iterate the keys and values in that or
- Use `Request.Params` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx and iterate the keys and values of that object.

The Ajax `data:` payload is then just your `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: Awesome thank you. This is so much easier. I went with FormCollection.